# Changing background color using JavaScript using id

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make an onclick button to change the background color of a div, using its id. My JavaScript function is as follows:

```
    function changeButton(color) {
      document.getElementById('button1').style.backgroundColor = color;
     }
```

and I'm linking to it in the HTML file like this:

```
    <script> src="websiteCleanJS.js" </script>
    .
    .
    .
    <div id='button1' onclick="changeButton('red')"> </div>
```

Comment: `<div id='button1', onclick('red')>` – that is total nonsense and miles away from valid syntax. You need to go learn some basics.

Comment: start from here, pleas: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/JavaScript_basics

Comment: In an odd twist your JavaScript syntax is fine but your HTML is wrong.

Comment: Accidentally copied it over wrong, sorry! @CBroe

Comment: Your click syntax is still incorrect. Should be `onclick="changeButton('red')"`

Comment: Whoops, forgot the '='... @j08691

Comment: OK but now the syntax for your script is incorrect. Dynamo's answer is correct. You can see it works here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/u1uayd1g/

Comment: Oh, yup, now I see it, I didnt realize I was closing the script tag before using the src attribute. @j08691

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
 <script src="websiteCleanJS.js"></script>
    .
    .
    .
    <div id='button1'  onclick="changeButton('red')"> </div>
```

Comment: Yup! Thats what I have in the actual file, posted it wrong here! For some reason its not changing the color when I click the button